# how can achieve layout like this

Tags: android, button, spinner

hey everyone m new to android

i m trying to get a layout like this[image]

but i have some confusions in

1. The greater than sign is not available by default in the Spinner
   for this i've also tried a button and setting it's background color to yellow but we can only define android:background for Button once than how can we define yellow color and greater than image buth in signle android:background statement??????
2. The Seekbar that is available by default doesn't look like the one i m looking for how can i get the one i m looking for?????

any help in this regard is highly appreciated.........

Comment: Dear Google, Please Force Developers To Follow Android Design Guidelines http://www.finitepost.com/post/29960507414/dear-google-please-force-developers-to-follow-android

Comment: you can use android:background for color and android:drawableRight for image:)

Comment: **[Follow Pure Android => Don't use right-pointing carets on line items](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)**

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
android:background
```

for color and

```
android:drawableRight
```

for image:) 
If you want slider as same as you want then you have to use image for both the slider and the handle of the slider. that takes a huge effort. anyhow if you want a Iphone like UI then research and carry on. My Best Wishes:)

Comment: You are welcome @khurramengr:) you can mark my answer as accepted then others can use this link:)